# Why can't ✳1.1 be expressed symbollically in Whitehead and Russell's PM?

Tags: logic, math-history, philosophy

> ✳1.1. Anything implied by a true elementary proposition is true. Pp.

In the follow passage, it says, "we cannot express the principle symbolically, partly because any symbolism in which p is variable only gives the *hypothesis* that p is true, not the *fact* that it is true."*

*The footnote refers to Russell's *Principles of Mathematics*, §38, but I don't understand how exactly Russell solved Lewis Carroll's puzzle, ["What the Tortoise said to Achilles."](http://www.ditext.com/carroll/tortoise.html)

Comment: You can see by Daniel J. O'Leary, *The Propositional Logic of Principia Mathematica and Some of Its Forerunners* (1988) in Russell: the Journal of Bertrand Russell Studies: Vol. 8: Iss.1

Comment: Found it online: [link](http://digitalcommons.mcmaster.ca/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1416&context=russelljournal) Thanks, @Mauro.

Comment: I have it. The "old" issues of the Journal are all freely available. There are a lot of interesting articles : Landini, Klement...

Comment: In O'Leary's paper [page 97] you can see the "translation" of 1.1. In modern logic [see Negri&von Plato, *Structural Proof Theory* (2001), page 3]: "Rules of inference are of the form: 'If it is the case that $A$ and $B$, then it is the case that $C$.' Thus they do not act on propositions, but on assertions. We obtain an assertion from a proposition $A$ by adding something to it, namely, an assertive mood such as '*it is the case that $A$.*' Frege used the assertion sign $\vdash A$ to indicate this but usually the distinction between propositions and assertions is left implicit."

Comment: The root cause is that an implication never asserts its constituent propositions. What is needed in the place of C is a general assertion i.e. ✳1.1; when C is accepted, A and B together constitute a particular case of C. In other words, A and B together do not lead to new discoveries, they only help the reader to "see" a particular case of C. This seems to be a recurring theme of Russell's work, namely deduction tells you what follows from your premises, but does not tell you whether your premises are true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About :

> ✳1.1. Anything implied by a true elementary proposition is true. Pp.

this is (a not very clear) formulation of *modus ponens*.

*Modus ponens* is an inference rule, so it is not "at the same level" of the laws of the calculus; in modern term, formula like $p \supset q$ are expressions in the language, but *modus ponens* is a *rule* fomulated in the meta-language, usually with *schemata*.

If you try to "download" *mp* in the languge, you will have :

> $\vdash (p \cdot (p \supset q) ) \supset q$

and this is valid also when $p$ is *false* and $q$ is *true*.

We want instead, that the rule license a sound argument. What we need is something like :

> $\frac {\vdash p \quad \vdash p \supset q}{\vdash q}$

The reference to Lewis Carroll is about the issue, discussed for the first time in "What the Tortoise said to Achilles", exactly about the role of "rules"; if I remeber well, was Carroll that argumented about the necessity of "postulating" rules that are not themselves "inferred", because in order to make a sound inference ... you need to apply a rule; this is the core of his paradox (a case of *regressus*). See the passage :

> "Readers of Euclid will grant, I suppose, that Z follows logically from A and B, so that any one who accepts A and B as true, must accept Z as true?"
>
> "Undoubtedly! The youngest child in a High School -- as soon as High Schools are invented, which will not be till some two thousand years later -- will grant that."
>
> "And if some reader had not yet accepted A and B as true, he might still accept the sequence as a valid one, I suppose?"
>
> "No doubt such a reader might exist. He might say 'I accept as true the Hypothetical Proposition that, if A and B be true, Z must be true; but, I don't accept A and B as true.' Such a reader would do wisely in abandoning Euclid, and taking to football."
>
> "And might there not also he some reader who would say 'I accept A and B as true, but I don't accept the Hypothetical '?"

Comment: As of this moment, I don't even see how Carroll's puzzle is related to *1.1.

Comment: @George Chen - the *regressus* of Carroll can be traduced as : "if $p$ is true and $p \supset q$ is true, then $q$ is true"; why ? because of the *rule*. So we really have : "if $p$ is true and $p \supset q$ is true **and** 'if $p$ and $p \supset q$ are true, then $q$ is true', then $q$ is true". Now do you see the *regressus* and the connection between the *validity* of the argument and the "assumption" about the *soundness* of the inference rule ? If you "download" the rule in the language, you will need a new rule in the meta-language ...

Comment: OK. The **sequence** can be accepted even if A and B are rejected. In other words, Carroll means to say that when a rule of implication is asserted, the constituent propositions are not necessarily asserted.

Comment: OK. I see the regression. The **sequence** is the hypothetical. If the **hypothetical** is rejected, then Z will not be logically concluded; but if the **hypothetical** is accepted, another hypothetical will be implicitly assumed. If the implicit one is brought to the fore and accepted, then another implicit one is immediately assumed.

Comment: Thanks, @Mauro. This is an interesting problem. _Principle_'s §38 is only the first step in answering Carroll's puzzle. It seems that the answer is in distinguishing **inference** from **implication**, and in setting apart **rule of inferences** from **premises of an implication**.

Comment: In other words, a rule of inference is not part of the hypothesis of an implication.

Comment: @George - **I think** that it is right ! This is basically the "lesson learned" from Lewis Carroll : you need to start somewhere. Modern logic, with *Natural Deduction*, shows us that we can "dispense with" axioms; but we cannot "dispense with" *rules*. Now it is "quite clear" ... It is remarkable the insight of Carroll. **P.S.** About PM $*1.1$, please note again the difficulty to articulate the (now so simple !) distinction between *language* nad *meta-language*.